# Simplifying only specific parts of polynomial expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have this expression :

```
1/4 (-Inactive[Cj][j]^2 - 2 Inactive[Cj][j]^3) Inactive[
    SixJSymbol][{j, j, j}, {j, j, j}] - 
 1/2 Inactive[Cj][j] Inactive[triple456][j, j, j, j, j, j]
```

[image]

As you can see, there is a "not simplified" polynomial in front of the `SixJSymbol`. I would like *Mathematica* to replace this part with `-(1/4) Inactive[Cj][j]^2 (1 + 2 Inactive[Cj][j])`, i.e. $((-1/4)Cj^2(1+2*Cj))$.

I could do this manually, but I want to know if it is possible to tell *Mathematica* something like : "Consider that I have a polynomial expression in `SixJSymbol` and `triple456`, I want that you simplify the factors in front of each of those terms". (If I basically do a `Simplify` here, I will no longer have a "factorisation" by `SixJsymbol` and `triple456`).

Is this possible ? If it is, I would like the simplest way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Collect) with [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) as the third argument:

```
expr= 1/4 (-Inactive[Cj][j]^2-2 Inactive[Cj][j]^3) Inactive[SixJSymbol][{j,j,j},{j,j,j}] -
    1/2 Inactive[Cj][j] Inactive[triple456][j,j,j,j,j,j];

Collect[
    expr,
    Inactive[SixJSymbol][__] | Inactive[triple456][__],
    Simplify
]
```

> -(1/4) Inactive[Cj][
>      j]^2 (1 + 2 Inactive[Cj][j]) Inactive[SixJSymbol][{j, j, j}, {j, j, j}] - 
>    1/2 Inactive[Cj][j] Inactive[triple456][j, j, j, j, j, j]

Comment: Collect is really magic, thanks !